# Cannot resolve SerializedName

Tags: android

I made a Bean Class but when i run it this is giving errors. I don't know how can i fix it. Please help me.

```
 Error:(7, 8) error: cannot find symbol class SerializedNameError:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

This is build.gradle:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.administrator.Myappliction"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}}   dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
compile files('libs/gson_1.7.jar')
compile files('libs/gson-2.2.4.jar')
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0"}
```

Comment: Tried cleaning your project? Have you included Gson in `build.gradle`?

Comment: i did but not working

Comment: Any  person have solution for me?????

Comment: Post your `build.gradle`.

Comment: @Shubham i have posted build.gradle

Comment: Why have you included 2 `gson JARs`?

Comment: i have removed one but still not working

Comment: I have  `import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;` in my class with SerializedName annatations and `compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7' ` in gradle dependencies and everything OK.

Comment: you can use Annotation @SerializedName("name of variable with exact Upper/Lowercase"), to map variables.

Answer (score 19):

just add     `implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'`

in your Gradle file(app)

Comment: in build.gradle(Module :app)

Answer (score 13):

in your model:

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
```

in build.gradel add gson and converter-gson

```
dependencies {
.
.
 implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
 implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I faced same issue. Finally solved.
I used both retrofit gson converter and google gson converter. I removed google gson converter and kept retrofit gson converter and this solved my problem.

I kept this: `implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'`
and removed this: `implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8'`

Answer (score 4):

Synching `gradle.build` file one more time solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Update gson lib to

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **retrofit2:converter-gson**

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
```

and then in your class

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName

data class DataClassName(
    @SerializedName("user")
    val userId: String,
    @SerializedName("bike")
    val bikeId: String,
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This error or warning usually comes when you use stuff which needs to be imported and added to dependencies:

```
Cannot resolve SerializedName
```

Add this in your gradle app file under dependencies like this:

```
dependencies {

implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'

}
```

**OR**:

```
dependencies {

implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8'

}
```

Now import it in your java class like this:
**eg:**

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update your gson dependencies. Add the below 2 lines and get resolve your issue

```
   implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
   implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.8'
```

Answer (score -1):

After add GSON dependency to your Gradle file and in your model, don't forget to make sure you have updated your GSON dependency to the latest version.